# Has Wonder Woman used her bracelets to direct bullets?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

I've recently been binging the Justice League cartoons on Netflix.  Many times in those cartoons Wonder Woman has performed the classic bullet deflection using her bracelets.  But the action always seems to be a simple deflection to stop the bullets hitting her (or someone standing behind her).

This got me thinking.  Has Wonder Woman ever used her bracelets to not just deflect projectiles, but to also deliberately aim them at a specific target?  IE has she ever performed something like what the Jedi do in re-directing blaster bolts?

I'll take answers from any version of Wonder Woman that could show this behavior.

Comment: Not sure about bullets, but she redirected Darkseid's Omega beams (back at his face) once.

Comment: She straight up shoots someone at one point; https://www.amazonarchives.com/wp-content/uploads/wonder-woman-volume-1-issue-168-page-30.jpg

Comment: She did it loads in the 1960s. Basically a couple of times each issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She directs bullets back at the guns that fired them in *[Wonder Woman #168](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_168)*

[image]

She directs a couple of artillery shells back to their originating ship in [*Wonder Woman #166*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_166)

[image]

She directs a figher-plane's bullets back toward it in [*Wonder Woman #161*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_161)

[image]

Comment: Now I want to know why she opened up that panel with "Hola"

Comment: @PeterM - She said that a lot in the 1960s. I think they were trying to make it into her catchphrase or something

Comment: To cater to the "Mujer Maravilla" crowd???

Comment: @PeterM - es posible!